# Is there way to loop through 3 sheets in the spreadsheet and compare the values and if found say true and if not false

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm very new to Macro. If you can help me get started, that would be great.
I have 3 sheets in the workbook. I have 4th sheet which contains email address. I would like to take each email address from 4th sheet and compare to other sheets. If found in sheet 1, create an column in the sheet 4 with name of sheet 1 say true else False.

Columns in Sht4:

```
  EmailAddress(B), Enabled, Name, Domain
```

I'm trying to build a Macro that will do that.

```
Sub vLookUpEmails()

    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim sht3 As Worksheet
    Dim sht4 As Worksheet

    Set sht1 = Sheets("h1")
    Set sht2 = Sheets("h2")
    Set sht3 = Sheets("h3")
    Set sht4 = Sheets("h4")

    'Creating columns in the sheet 4

    sht4.Columns("H:H").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("H1").Value = "h1"

    sht4.Columns("I:I").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("I1").Value = "h2"

    sht4.Columns("J:J").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("J1").Value = "h3"

    'Getting last row
    combLastRow = sht1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

End Sub
```

I expect in sht 4. Creates Columns H1, H2, H3. In each of the column, it says true or false if email address found in the sht1 then in h1 column, it will say true else false.

Comment: You shouldn't create the columns each time, just once (though you could do that manually). How many rows you have/expect to have in these sheets?

Comment: What column has the addresses?  are the sheet names `h#` or `AA`,`UiPath`,...?

Comment: Sht 1 to 3 data comes from database. Combine they have about 600 email address. In Sht 4 only brings data of email address that are longer with the company. which is about 20-30 rows. I just want sht4 email address to find in the sht1,2,3 then say i found this in sht1 write the value true in sht 4

Comment: @ScottCraner in Sht4 - Email are in Columns B and In Sht 1,2,3: Email are in Column A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just try to use the match formula and see if a number is returned or not:

```
With sht4
    Dim lstrw As Long
    lstrw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    With .Range(.Cells(2, 8), .Cells(lstrw, 10))
        .Formula = "=ISNUMBER(MATCH($B2,INDIRECT(""'"" & H$1 & ""'!$A:$A""),0))"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With
```

[image]

- Sheet1 has `2004` and `2005` in column A
- Sheet2 has `2006` in Column A
- Sheet3 has `2007` in Column A

Comment: How is this comparing to  other 3 sheets?

Comment: When the formula is put across all three columns the `H$1` will change to reference `I$1` and `J$1` and as such, if the text in the column headers match the sheet names it will reference the correct sheet.

Comment: Just to be clear, the code will do the reference changes.  It is akin to putting the formula in H2, copying over and down.  Excel will change the relative references on its own.

Comment: Thanks. is there way to make it type/write to say True or False in sht 4 if it matches it?

Comment: This does that.  This will fill columns H to J from row 2 to the last row that has an address in column B on sht4 with either `TRUE` or `FALSE`  It will not change the cells on any other sheet.  The one caveat is that the headers of those column must have the correct sheet names.

Comment: Thanks Scott. One more Question. I replicated what you had. It makes B column all "0".


          combLastRow = sht1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
          With sht4
        Dim lstrw As Long
        lstrw = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("B2:B" & lstrw)
        .Formula = 
        "=ISNUMBER(MATCH($B2,INDIRECT(""'"" & H$1 & 
            ""'!$A:$A""),0))"
        .Value = .Value
                End With
        End With

Comment: It should not do anything to column B.  The code, at least the part I gave you, only effects Column H:J

Comment: why did you change it to `With .Range("B2:B" & lstrw)`

Comment: because i wanted to go through all B column in sht4. I thought your cell only go through 8.

Comment: `8` is the column number, which equates to column `H`.  `lstrw = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row` is what causes it to include all of column B.  The code will work as is, no need to change.  No loop is needed.

Comment: Thanks Scott for your help. Appreciate it. Got it working

Comment: one last question I promise: how do I change if sheet 2 has address in column B

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Comment: I mean currently it looks through all "A" Columns in each sheet. I found out that Email Address in Sheet 2 are in column B. Do I need to the change $A:$A?

Comment: Then you will need to split it into three separate formulas, one for each column.  Try it on your own.  If you get stuck come back and ask a new question, as that is changing the criteria from the original asked question.